Application of Hahn-Banach Theorem, there exists a specific bounded linear functional
I am reading Real Analysis written by Folland and in Theorem 5.8(a) he claims that:
Let $X$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. If $M$ is a closed subspace of $X$ and $x\in X\setminus M$, then there exists $f\in X^{*}$ such that $f|_M = 0$, $f(x)\neq 0$ and $||f|| = 1$.
Here is the proof:
Let $\delta = \inf_{y\in M}||x-y||$. Consider the linear functional $f$ on $M + \mathbb{C}x$ defined by $f(y + \lambda x) = \lambda\delta$. If $\lambda \neq 0$, then $|f(y + \lambda x)| = |\lambda|\delta\leq |\lambda|\cdot||\lambda^{-1}y + x\|| = ||y + \lambda x||$. Hence we can extend $f$ to $F\in X^{*}$ which satisfies the condition.
I see why $F|_M = 0$, $F(x)\neq 0$ and $||F||\leq 1$. However, I don't see why the norm of $F$ is exactly one. Could anyone help me with that?
Thank you!!
Edit: solved

I think you should add the result that $|f(x)|=1$ as well.

The proof already shows that $|f(y + \lambda x)| \leq |y + \lambda x|$, that is to say, $|f| \leq 1$ on $M + \mathbb{C}x$. The extension may be chosen to have the same norm, which is part of Hahn-Banach theorem.

@DavidGao Then $||F||\leq 1$, but might not be 1.

@LidingYao But even though it still doesn't show that $||F|| = 1$?

@Coco It isn’t really hard to show $|f| \geq 1$. Indeed, $\delta = \inf_{y \in M} |x-y|$, so for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $y \in M$ s.t. $|x-y| < (1 + \epsilon)\delta$. Thus, $|f(x-y)| = \delta > \frac{|x-y|}{1+\epsilon}$, so $|f| > \frac{1}{1+\epsilon}$. Letting $\epsilon \to 0$ shows $|f| \geq 1$. Folland probably considered this obvious so he didn’t write it down or something.

Thank you so much!! @DavidGao May I wonder how did you come up with such a proof? It seems that I am lack of exercise.

@Coco This is sort of a very standard argument. For intuition, $\inf_{y \in M} |x-y|$ is the norm of $x+M$ in the quotient space $X/M$. So if you regard $f$ as a linear functional on $X/M$, $f$ just sends $x+M$ to its norm, which then directly means $|f| \geq 1$. My argument is basically just “pulling back” the argument on the quotient space to directly on $X$. These kinds of arguments should become more obvious to you once you have more experience working with norms.

@DavidGao Thank you so much!
